# Previewing Nuxt3 site with layer0 giving error "Failed to load module script"

Tags: nuxtjs3

Steps to reproduce:

1). run 'npx nuxi init test'

2). run 'cd test'

3). run 'yarn install'

4). run 'NITRO_PRESET=layer0 yarn build'

5). run 'cd .output'

6). run 'npm run preview'

7). open localhost:3000

8). check console for error.

Full error is "error: Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

When I look at the mjs file that is being sent it looks like html. This is leading me to believe that for some reason layer0 is sending the wrong file with nitro server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I decided to use another provider.